# Internet Explorer 10 - new line break insted of spaces

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

I have a page menu based on JavaScript where menu items are generated from a database. Simple menu system looks like

```
function LoadMenus() {
window.fw_menu_1 = new Menu("root",165,17,"Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",11,"#ffffff","#000000","#597B7B","#FFF9DC","left","middle",4,0,1000,-5,7,true,true,true,5,true,true);

       fw_menu_1.addMenuItem("Menu Item 1","location='#'");

       fw_menu_1.addMenuItem("Menu Item 2","location='#'");

       fw_menu_1.addMenuItem("Menu Item 3","location='#'");

       fw_menu_1.addMenuItem("Menu Item 4","location='#'");

       fw_menu_1.addMenuItem("Menu Item 5","location='#'");

       fw_menu_1.addMenuItem("Menu&nbsp;Item&nbsp;6","location='#'");

      fw_menu_1.hideOnMouseOut=true;
}
```

First that menu wasn't displayed at all on IE10 till I used

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

But when I was able to display menu all items have new line breaks instead spaced except Menu Item 6 where I have replaced regular space with a tag for non-breaking space.

Any clue why IE10 is switching all regular spaces to new line breaks?

Thanks

Per request

```
function Menu(label, mw, mh, fnt, fs, fclr, fhclr, bg, bgh, halgn, valgn, pad, space, to, sx, sy, srel, opq, vert, idt, aw, ah) 
{
    this.version = "020320 [Menu; mm_menu.js]";
    this.type = "Menu";
    this.menuWidth = mw;
    this.menuItemHeight = mh;
    this.fontSize = fs;
    this.fontWeight = "plain";
    this.fontFamily = fnt;
    this.fontColor = fclr;
    this.fontColorHilite = fhclr;
    this.bgColor = "#ffffff";
    this.menuBorder = 1;
    this.menuBgOpaque=opq;
    this.menuItemBorder = 1;
    this.menuItemIndent = idt;
    this.menuItemBgColor = bg;
    this.menuItemVAlign = valgn;
    this.menuItemHAlign = halgn;
    this.menuItemPadding = pad;
    this.menuItemSpacing = space;
    this.menuLiteBgColor = "#ffffff";
    this.menuBorderBgColor = "#777777";
    this.menuHiliteBgColor = bgh;
    this.menuContainerBgColor = "#ffffff";
    this.childMenuIcon = "arrows.gif";
    this.submenuXOffset = sx;
    this.submenuYOffset = sy;
    this.submenuRelativeToItem = srel;
    this.vertical = vert;
    this.items = new Array();
    this.actions = new Array();
    this.childMenus = new Array();
    this.hideOnMouseOut = true;
    this.hideTimeout = to;
    this.addMenuItem = addMenuItem;
    this.writeMenus = writeMenus;
    this.MM_showMenu = MM_showMenu;
    this.onMenuItemOver = onMenuItemOver;
    this.onMenuItemAction = onMenuItemAction;
    this.hideMenu = hideMenu;
    this.hideChildMenu = hideChildMenu;
    if (!window.menus) window.menus = new Array();
    this.label = " " + label;
    window.menus[this.label] = this;
    window.menus[window.menus.length] = this;
    if (!window.activeMenus) window.activeMenus = new Array();
}

function addMenuItem(label, action) {
    this.items[this.items.length] = label;
    this.actions[this.actions.length] = action;
}
```

Comment: And we are supposed to know what addMenuItem is?

Comment: Added both scripts. No clue if it is related to Macromedia JS part or not, but is strange to have replaced spaces with a new line breaks :\

Comment: @JackTheKnife Are you using Dreamweaver?

Comment: @Samuel yes, that menu system is based on rollover menus from an old Dreamweaver version. Was working fine till IE10 ;)

Comment: @JackTheKnife do you have a live demo of this somewhere?

Comment: @Samuel here: http://www.uscib.org/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to follow the steps in the following document by Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh779632.aspx. Also try running it through the scanner on modern.ie: http://www.modern.ie/report#http%3A%2F%2Fuscib.org%20 This detects common issues.

For example, you are using a X-UA-Compatible meta tag that is forcing IE10 to render in IE8 mode. Changing the content to value to edge will tell IE to use the latest mode available

Then you do not have a doctype so it will render in quirksmode, rather than standards mode. As the script is old and has all sorts of non-standards code like document.all, it may be that IE is tripping up between this and the correct code it should be using if you put it in standards mode. Add a HTML5 doctype to the very top of your page to try to mitigate these issues:

Comment: Well, still no luck. Doctype added and same result. So far I was able to see menus populated properly when IE10 development window I have set to IE5 quirks

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provided in the comments, you are missing a DOCTYPE.

http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Try this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

This goes before your opening  tag.

Comment: Thanks, will test that option ASAP. I was thinking that missing doctype can be an issue, but I wasn't able to find anywhere confirmation on that matter and IE10.

Comment: I have added doctype but still no luck. See response below when I was able to get spaces rendering properly.